# Prevent Vue.Js replace Twig content in mounting DOM element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, twig

Version: **Vue 3.0.5**

**index.html.twig**

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h3>My text rendered in Twig</h3>
            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                <example></example>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**entry-file.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';

import Example from './components/Example.vue'

createApp(Example).mount('#app');
```

**components/Example.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>This is text from VueJs component</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'example'
}
</script>
```

Currently, when I access the page Vue completely removes Twig content inside #app div and replaces it with text from the component.

My question are,

1. How can I keep initial `#app` content rendered by Twig and additionally compile `<example></example>` component by Vue?
2. Is it OK practice to mix it this way? The problem is that I already have blocks/widgets and custom logic based on backed variables in Twig and it will be far too long to rewrite everything in Vue

Comment: Can try such option
```
import { createApp } from 'vue';

import Example from './components/Example.vue'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(Example)
app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070304/load-vue-3-component-inside-mounted-div-and-pass-php-data

Comment: Thanks for the reference! 
But sorry, I didn't mention that I don't use Encore but instead just plain webpack configs

Comment: I'm interested in any solution, same problem here...